# How to delete a branch and all the objects it referenced

Tags: git

The issue is that after your delete and push branch it isn't lost forever and it is still in repository.
I've deleted branch with big amount of needless files, but as long it is still somewhere in git repository, git clone command duration is too big.

For now only way I see is to delete whole repository and recreate it but without needless branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [`git gc --prune=now`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) will do what you want: clean up unnecessary files from your repository.

By default `git gc` removes unreachable commits older than 2 weeks, so adding `--prune=now` is what you need.

Comment: +1 git gc will indeed clean up loose objects in the repository. However, the problem with clone taking a lot of time is related to old file revisions still residing in the repo.

Comment: Thanks for prune, will edit my question. I don't agree, if the commits that were deleted are unreachable (which seems to be the case), they'll get deleted by `prune`

Comment: The reason is the reflog, which contains references to the states of your branches even if the branches are already deleted.

Comment: Seems to be the case, yes. Still, the time it takes to clone a repository is still not related to loose objects in your repository. It doesn't matter if you have 1Gb of loose objects, cloning that repository will not clone the loose objects.

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove files completely by using **git filter-branch**

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

You can do a lot of magic with this command, the following will remove filename from all commits:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f filename' HEAD
```

Comment: just curious: if the commit is gone, since the branch is deleted, isn't `git gc` removing it?

Comment: @CharlesB: Yep but you might want to use git gc --prune=now to get rid of all data. However, this is only data for the local repository and doesn't have any effect when cloning it. It seems this question is two folded.